# If $G$ is generated by a subgroup $S$ and $\sigma$ is an automorphism in $G$, then $\sigma(S)$ generates $G$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Assume that $G$ is a group such that a subset of $G$ like $S$ can generate $G$.
Prove that:

> If $\sigma$ is an automorphism in $G$, Then $\sigma(S)$ generates $G$,
>   too.

Note: If $S$ generates $G$, it means that The cyclic group generated by the elements of $S$ is equal to $G$. So, How does an isomorphism from $G$ to itself (an automorphism called $\sigma$), become useful here? Can we say that $\sigma(S) = S$ ? (Because $\sigma$ is bijective?)

Comment: If $ S $ generates $ G $, then clearly $ \sigma(S) $ generates $ \sigma(G) $. Now, what might $ \sigma(G) $ be..?

Comment: $\sigma$ sends generating set to a generating set.  But $\sigma(S)=S$ is not true. $\mathbb{Z}=<1>=<-1>$ then $\sigma(1)=-1$ is also true but $1\neq-1$

Comment: @SaeidAli How do you prove that $\sigma$ sends generating set to a generating set? That's what the question wants!

Comment: $S$ does not necessarily generate a cyclic group.

Comment: @Starfall You say $\sigma(G) = G$?

Comment: automorphisms are onto.

Comment: Since $S$ is a generating set and $\sigma$ is an automorphism so the image of $S$ by $\sigma$ must generate $G$.

Comment: Note that an automorphism is an isomorphism from a mathematical object to itself

Comment: @SaeidAli the statement you said is just the one that questions wants us to prove! How do you know "it must generate $G$"? I know that the statement is right but that's not a formal proof!

Comment: Suppose $S$ generates $G$, then for all $g_i \in G$, we can find $s_{i1}, \dots s_{i k_i} \in S$ such that $g_i = s_{i1} \dots s_{i k_i}$. So $\sigma(g_i) = \sigma(s_{i1}) \dots \sigma(s_{i k_i})$. Hence we have $\{ \sigma(s_{i1}), \dots \sigma(s_{i k_i}) \}$ generates $\sigma(G)$. It follows $\sigma(S)$ generates $\sigma(G) = G$.

Comment: From universal algebra: Let $g\in G$ and $S$ generates $G$ there is implicit operation $f$ (composition product, inverse and identity) such that $g=f(S)$. As $f$ is implicit operation it commutes with homomorphisms $\sigma f=f\sigma$. Then $f(\sigma(S))=\sigma(f(S))$. Note that if $S$ generate $G$, we have $G=\{f(S)\mid f ~\text{is an implicit operation}\}$. $\sigma(G)=\sigma(\{f(S)\mid f ~\text{is an implicit operation}\})=\{\sigma(f(S))\mid f ~\text{is an implicit operation}\}=\{f(\sigma(S))\mid f ~\text{is an implicit operation}\}$ which implies $\sigma(S)$ generates $\sigma(G)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An automorphism is an isomorphism of a group between itself. Note that $\sigma$ is then a homomorphism. Since $\sigma$ is 1-to-1 in the whole group $G$, it is 1-to-1 in $S$. Then

$$\sigma : S \to \sigma(S)$$

Becomes a 1-to-1 and onto homomorphism. A group under a homomorphism is a group too so clearly we have $\sigma(S) \le G$.

Let the set $A \subset S$ generate $S$. Note that $A$ could be either a proper or improper subset of $S$. We are given that $A$ generates G. Let $A=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ for any element $k \epsilon S$

$$\sigma(k)=\sigma((x_1n_1)(x_2n_2)...(x_nn_n))=\sigma(x_1)\sigma(n_1)...\sigma(x_n)\sigma(n_n)$$

Since $\sigma$ is an homomorphism.Since $\sigma$ is ONTO, clearly we can see from the equation above that for $\sigma$ to generate all elements of $\sigma(S)$ It's image of the generator should be a generator.

then $\sigma(A)=A$

The result follows.

Comment: "1-to-1 in $S$" is more than unclear.

Comment: What is $K$? It's not defined!

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade Typo, Should have been $S$. Does my approach make sense? Feel free to ask.

Comment: @user1952009 If a function is 1-to-1 in $A$ then it would be 1-to-1 in $B \subset A $, why unclear?

Comment: 1-to-1 $S \to \sigma(S)$ is clear, but "1-to-1 onto homomorphism" is again unclear. Really the best approach is in starfall's comment : since $\sigma$ is a group isomorphism, $S$ generates $G$ means that $\sigma(S)$ generates $\sigma(G)$

Comment: What are $n_i$'s?

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade Since $k \epsilon S$ And $A$ generates $S$ and $G$, I can find the corresponding $n_i \epsilon Z^{+}$